# Apache NIFI: Occasional Exception with PUTSQL Processor java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: java, mariadb, apache-nifi

I'm encountering occasional Exception when using PUTSQL processor in apache Nifi.

I have already Increased `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` But I'm still encountering the error occasionally. How can I fix this error? And what are the optimal configurations when using putsql processor to insert large volume of records into mariadb?

[image]

[image]

```
Variable_name;Value
innodb_lock_wait_timeout;300

Error Snippet:
2023-11-24 18:04:45,837 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-51] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=c7255d17-018b-1000-143e-fc839881330c] Failed to update database due to a failed batch update, java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction. There were a total of 1 FlowFiles that failed, 14 that succeeded, and 0 that were not execute and will be routed to retry;
        java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:224)
```

Comment: How does your Fetch Size setting affect how often you see the error? Maybe start with 2000 and see if you can increase all the way to 20000 and still get performance benefits without the error (or at least it happening as often). Another recommendation (this should probably be required) is to set the Validation Query property so a connection is not reused if it shouldn't be